# Web Notification Design

Tags: social-networking, notification

I am designing a website which my web user would interact on the site.

Take FB poke function for example. There are two men A and B and they are both online. And A poked B.

What I want to know is how to make B get an instant notification, knowing that A poked him just now ?

The way I thought is that make a javascript code to ajax the database for new notification every minutes. How could I reduce the amount of the times of query the data ?

Or is there any other way better?

Answer (score 2):

You can use WebSockets, a very good library for it is Socket.io. Then you can emit an event serverside and the client gets it immediately.

Comment: It's for `node.js` If I use php and javascript only, how could I do?